# Replacing fermionic operators with their Fourier transform and boundary conditions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-information, fourier-transform, fermions

In the section 4.1 of [Quantum Computation by Adiabatic Evolution](http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0001106v1.pdf), Farhi et al proposes a quantum adiabatic algorithm to solve the $2$-SAT problem on a ring. To compute the complexity of the algorithm the authors computed the energy gap between the ground and first excited states of the 
adiabatic Hamiltonian.

The adiabatic Hamiltonian is defined as 
$$
\tilde{H} (s) = (1-s) \sum^n_{j=1}(1-\sigma^{(j)}_x) + s \sum^n_{j=1}\frac{1}{2} (1-\sigma^{(j)}_z \sigma^{(j+1)}_z )
$$

Then the adiabatic Hamiltonian is reexpressed using fermionic operators as follows.

$$
\tilde{H}(s) = \sum^n_{j=1} \left\{2 (1-s)b^\dagger_j b_j + \frac{s}{2}(1-(b^\dagger_j - b_j)(b^\dagger_{j+1} + b_{j+1}))\right\}
$$

Then the authors takes the Fourier transform of the fermionic operators,

$$\beta_p =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum^n_{j=1} e^{i\pi p j/n} b_j$$
where $p = \pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots, \pm \left(n-1\right)$,

and rewrite the adiabatic Hamiltonian as

$$\tilde{H}(s) = \sum_{p = \pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots, \pm \left(n-1\right)} A_p (s)$$
where
$$
A_p (s) = 2 (1-s)[\beta^\dagger_p \beta_p + \beta^\dagger_{-p} \beta_{-p}] + s \left\{1 - \cos\frac{\pi p}{n} [\beta^\dagger_p \beta_p - \beta_{-p} \beta^\dagger_{-p}] + i \sin \frac{\pi p}{n}[\beta^\dagger_{-p} \beta^\dagger_{p} - \beta_{p} \beta_{-p}]\right\}.
$$

**My question:**

How can I derive the second part i.e. $s \left\{1 - \cos\frac{\pi p}{n} [\beta^\dagger_p \beta_p - \beta_{-p} \beta^\dagger_{-p}] + i \sin \frac{\pi p}{n}[\beta^\dagger_{-p} \beta^\dagger_{p} - \beta_{p} \beta_{-p}]\right\}$?

**My attempt:**

We compute few quantities.

$$
\beta^\dagger_p \beta_p = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum^n_{k=1}e^{-i\pi p k/n}b^\dagger_k\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum^n_{j=1}e^{i\pi p j/n}b_j\right)
\\
=\frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{k,j=1}e^{-i\pi p (k-j)/n} b^\dagger_k b_j
$$,

$$
\beta^\dagger_{-p} \beta_{-p} = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum^n_{k=1} e^{i\pi p k/n} b^\dagger_k\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum^n_{j=1} e^{-i\pi p j/n} b_j\right)
\\
=\frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{k,j=1}e^{i\pi p (k-j)/n} b^\dagger_k b_j
$$,

$$
\beta_{-p} \beta^\dagger_{-p} = \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum^n_{j=1} e^{-i\pi p j/n} b_j\right)\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum^n_{k=1} e^{i\pi p k/n} b^\dagger_k\right)
\\
=\frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{k,j=1}e^{i\pi p (k-j)/n} b_j b^\dagger_k
$$,

$$
\beta^\dagger_{-p} \beta^\dagger_{p} = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum^n_{j=1} e^{i\pi p j/n} b^\dagger_j\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum^n_{k=1} e^{-i\pi p k/n} b^\dagger_k\right)
\\
=\frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{k,j=1}e^{-i\pi p (k-j)/n} b^\dagger_j b^\dagger_k
$$,

and

$$
\beta_{p} \beta_{-p} = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum^n_{j=1} e^{i\pi p j/n} b_j\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum^n_{k=1} e^{-i\pi p k/n} b_k\right)
\\
=\frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{k,j=1}e^{-i\pi p (k-j)/n} b_j b_k
$$.

We also compute two linear combinations of these quantities.

\begin{align}
\beta^\dagger_{p} \beta_{p} - \beta_{-p} \beta^\dagger_{-p} &=  \frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{k,j=1}e^{-i\pi p (k-j)/n} b^\dagger_k b_j - \frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{k,j=1}e^{i\pi p (k-j)/n} b_j b^\dagger_k
\nonumber\\
&=  \frac{1}{n} \left( \sum^n_{k,j=1}e^{-i\pi p (k-j)/n} b^\dagger_k b_j -  \sum^n_{k,j=1}e^{i\pi p (k-j)/n} b_j b^\dagger_k\right)
\nonumber\\
&=  \frac{1}{n} \left( \sum^n_{k,j=1}\left(\cos \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right) - i \sin \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right)\right) b^\dagger_k b_j \right.
\nonumber\\
& \left. -  \sum^n_{k,j=1} \left(\cos \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right) + i \sin \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right) \right) b_j b^\dagger_k\right)
\nonumber\\
&=  \frac{1}{n}  \sum^n_{k,j=1} \left(\left(\cos \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right) - i \sin \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right)\right) b^\dagger_k b_j \right.
\nonumber\\
& \left. -  \left(\cos \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right) + i \sin \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right) \right) b_j b^\dagger_k\right)
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
\beta^\dagger_{-p} \beta^\dagger_{p} - \beta_{p} \beta_{-p} &=  \frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{k,j=1}e^{-i\pi p (k-j)/n} b^\dagger_j b^\dagger_k - \frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{k,j=1}e^{-i\pi p (k-j)/n} b_j b_k
\nonumber\\
&=  \frac{1}{n} \left( \sum^n_{k,j=1}e^{-i\pi p (k-j)/n} b^\dagger_j b^\dagger_k -  \sum^n_{k,j=1}e^{-i\pi p (k-j)/n} b_j b_k\right)
\nonumber\\
&=  \frac{1}{n} \left( \sum^n_{k,j=1}\left(\cos \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right) - i \sin \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right)\right) b^\dagger_j b^\dagger_k \right.
\nonumber\\
& \left.-  \sum^n_{k,j=1}\left(\cos \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right) - i \sin \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right)\right) b_j b_k\right)
\nonumber\\
&=  \frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{k,j=1} \left( \left(\cos \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right) - i \sin \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right)\right) b^\dagger_j b^\dagger_k \right.
\nonumber\\
& \left.- \left(\cos \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right) - i \sin \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right)\right) b_j b_k\right)
\end{align}.

So, 
\begin{align}
1 - \cos \frac{\pi p}{n}\left[\beta^\dagger_p \beta_p - \beta_{-p}  \beta^\dagger_{-p}\right] + i \sin \frac{\pi p}{n} \left[\beta^\dagger_{-p} \beta^\dagger_p - \beta_p \beta_{-p}\right] =
\nonumber\\
 1 - \cos \frac{\pi p}{n}\left[\frac{1}{n}  \sum^n_{k,j=1} \left(\left(\cos \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right) - i \sin \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right)\right) b^\dagger_k b_j \right. \right.
\nonumber\\
 -  \left. \left.  \left(\cos \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right) + i \sin \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right) \right) b_j b^\dagger_k\right)\right] 
 \nonumber\\
 + i \sin \frac{\pi p}{n} \left[\frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{k,j=1} \left( \left(\cos \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right) - i \sin \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right)\right) b^\dagger_j b^\dagger_k \right. \right.
  \nonumber\\
 - \left. \left. \left(\cos \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right) - i \sin \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right)\right) b_j b_k\right)\right]
 \nonumber\\
= 1 - \frac{1}{n} \cos \frac{\pi p}{n}\left[  \sum^n_{k,j=1} \left(\left(\cos \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right) - i \sin \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right)\right) b^\dagger_k b_j \right. \right.
\nonumber\\
 -  \left. \left.  \left(\cos \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right) + i \sin \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right) \right) b_j b^\dagger_k\right)\right] 
 \nonumber\\
 + \frac{1}{n}i \sin \frac{\pi p}{n} \left[ \sum^n_{k,j=1} \left( \left(\cos \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right) - i \sin \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right)\right) b^\dagger_j b^\dagger_k \right. \right.
  \nonumber\\
 - \left. \left. \left(\cos \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right) - i \sin \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right)\right) b_j b_k\right)\right]
  \nonumber\\
= 1 - \frac{1}{n} \left[  \sum^n_{k,j=1} \left(\left(\cos \frac{\pi p}{n} \cos \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right) - i\cos \frac{\pi p}{n} \sin \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right)\right) b^\dagger_k b_j \right. \right.
\nonumber\\
 -  \left. \left.  \left(\cos \frac{\pi p}{n} \cos \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right) + i \cos \frac{\pi p}{n} \sin \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right) \right) b_j b^\dagger_k\right)\right] 
 \nonumber\\
 + \frac{1}{n}i  \left[ \sum^n_{k,j=1} \left( \left(\sin \frac{\pi p}{n} \cos \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right) - i \sin \frac{\pi p}{n} \sin \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right)\right) b^\dagger_j b^\dagger_k \right. \right.
  \nonumber\\
 - \left. \left. \left(\sin \frac{\pi p}{n} \cos \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right) - i \sin \frac{\pi p}{n} \sin \left(\pi p (k-j)/n\right)\right) b_j b_k\right)\right]
\end{align}

I am not sure how to get to $1-(b^\dagger_j - b_j)(b^\dagger_{j+1} + b_{j+1})$ from here.

**Update 1:**

Following the comment by @mas, I am starting with Eq. 4.14 i.e. the inverse Fourier transform.

\begin{align}
b_j &=  \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{p = \pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots, \pm \left(n-1\right)} e^{-i\pi p j/n} \beta_p
\end{align}

So,

$$
\sum^n_{j=1} (b^\dagger_j - b_j)(b^\dagger_{j+1} + b_{j+1}) = \\
\sum^n_{j=1}  (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{p = \pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots, \pm \left(n-1\right)} e^{i\pi p j/n} \beta^\dagger_p - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{p = \pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots, \pm \left(n-1\right)} e^{-i\pi p j/n} \beta_p)(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{p = \pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots, \pm \left(n-1\right)} e^{i\pi p (j+1)/n} \beta^\dagger_p + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{p = \pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots, \pm \left(n-1\right)} e^{-i\pi p (j+1)/n} \beta_p)
\\
=\sum^n_{j=1}  \frac{1}{n} ( \sum_{p = \pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots, \pm \left(n-1\right)} e^{i\pi p j/n} \beta^\dagger_p -  \sum_{p = \pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots, \pm \left(n-1\right)} e^{-i\pi p j/n} \beta_p)( \sum_{p = \pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots, \pm \left(n-1\right)} e^{i\pi p (j+1)/n} \beta^\dagger_p +  \sum_{p = \pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots, \pm \left(n-1\right)} e^{-i\pi p (j+1)/n} \beta_p)
\\
=\sum^n_{j=1}  \frac{1}{n} ( \sum_{p = \pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots, \pm \left(n-1\right)} e^{i\pi p j/n} \beta^\dagger_p \sum_{q = \pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots, \pm \left(n-1\right)} e^{i\pi q (j+1)/n} \beta^\dagger_q -  \sum_{p = \pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots, \pm \left(n-1\right)} e^{-i\pi p j/n} \beta_p \sum_{q = \pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots, \pm \left(n-1\right)} e^{i\pi q (j+1)/n} \beta^\dagger_q + \sum_{p = \pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots, \pm \left(n-1\right)} e^{i\pi p j/n} \beta^\dagger_p \sum_{q = \pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots, \pm \left(n-1\right)} e^{-i\pi q (j+1)/n} \beta_q -  \sum_{p = \pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots, \pm \left(n-1\right)} e^{-i\pi p j/n} \beta_p \sum_{q = \pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots, \pm \left(n-1\right)} e^{-i\pi q (j+1)/n} \beta_q)
\\
=\sum^n_{j=1}  \frac{1}{n} ( \sum_{p,q = \pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots, \pm \left(n-1\right)} e^{i\pi p j/n}   e^{i\pi q (j+1)/n} \beta^\dagger_p \beta^\dagger_q -  \sum_{p,q = \pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots, \pm \left(n-1\right)} e^{-i\pi p j/n}   e^{i\pi q (j+1)/n} \beta_p \beta^\dagger_q + \sum_{p,q = \pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots, \pm \left(n-1\right)} e^{i\pi p j/n}   e^{-i\pi q (j+1)/n} \beta^\dagger_p \beta_q -  \sum_{p,q = \pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots, \pm \left(n-1\right)} e^{-i\pi p j/n}   e^{-i\pi q (j+1)/n} \beta_p \beta_q)
$$

I am still stuck.

Comment: Instead of starting with (4.13), If you start with the inverse transformation given by equation (4.14) can carry out the calculation you have done. that will lead the desired expression.

Comment: Any idea why $p$ takes only odd values instead of the usual $0,1,\ldots,n-1$?

Comment: @mas, I tried the way you suggested. It is shown under Update 1 in the quesiion body. I am not sure whether I am getting closer.

Comment: @leongz, the even values are covered by the periodic boundary condition.

Comment: @Omar Shehab, Your updated approach is correct and its working (i checked it.)

Comment: @mas, I am not sure how to proceed. Let's take the first sum. $\sum^n_{j=1}  \frac{1}{n} ( \sum_{p,q = \pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots, \pm \left(n-1\right)} e^{i\pi p j/n}   e^{i\pi q (j+1)/n} \beta^\dagger_p \beta^\dagger_q )$. What should be my next intuition to simplify it?

Comment: @mas, why isn't there a contribution when $p \ne q$?

Comment: @Omar Shehab, when $p=q$, that gives a contribution like $e^{2\pi\theta} e^{\frac{ip\pi }{n}}$.
Then we have to use $e^{2\pi\theta}=1$. There is a sum over $p$  in $\beta_{p}^{\dagger}\beta_{p}^{\dagger}$. As $\beta's$ are Fermioni c that is why $\beta^{2}=0$. Therefore only the terms survive in the sum over $p$ must comes with opposite sign of $p$. Which is in fact leads the term $\beta^{\dagger}_{-p}\beta^{\dagger}_{p}+\text{hermition conjugate}$ with a $i\sin\theta$-multiplied with it.

Comment: @mas, thank you very much for explaining. In case you have missed my previous question, why isn't there a contribution when $p \ne q$?

Comment: $b^{\dagger}_{j}b_{j}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{p,q}e^{\frac{ij\pi (q-p)}{n}}\beta_{q}^{\dagger}\beta_{q}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{p,q}n\delta_{pq}\beta_{q}^{\dagger}\beta_{p}=\sum_{p}\beta_{p}^{\dagger}\beta_{p}=\beta_{p}^{\dagger}\beta_{p}+\beta_{-p}^{\dagger}\beta_{-p}$. This is the first term.

Comment: Thats because $q$ is nothing but a dummy index.

Comment: @mas, Thanks for your reply. It was helpful. I have a minor question. According to the Wikipedia, the Kronecker Delta function is defined as follows. $$\delta_{pq} = \frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{k=1} e^{2 \pi i \frac{k}{n}(p-q)} $$. I see that there is no factor of $2$ in the exponent of the sum in your comment. Can you still replace it with a delta function?

Comment: The periodicity condition for your problem is not the same of Wikipedia. Both results are same up to a normalization factor.

Comment: @mas, here I present how I am computing  all the terms of the following. \begin{align}
\left(b^\dagger_j - b_j\right)\left(b^\dagger_{j+1} + b_{j+1}\right) &= b^\dagger_j b^\dagger_{j+1} - b_j b^\dagger_{j+1} + b^\dagger_j b_{j+1} - b_j b_{j+1}\end{align}

Comment: \begin{align}
b^\dagger_j b^\dagger_{j+1} &=    \left(\cos \frac{\pi p}{n} + i \sin \frac{\pi p}{n} \right)     \beta^\dagger_{-p}  \beta^\dagger_p + \left(\cos \frac{\pi p}{n} - i \sin \frac{\pi p}{n} \right)     \beta^\dagger_{p}  \beta^\dagger_{-p}
\nonumber\\
b_j b^\dagger_{j+1}  &=  \left(\cos \frac{\pi p}{n} + i \sin \frac{\pi p}{n} \right)     \beta_p  \beta^\dagger_p +  \left(\cos \frac{\pi p}{n} - i \sin \frac{\pi p}{n} \right)     \beta_{-p}  \beta^\dagger_{-p}
\end{align}

Comment: \begin{align}
b^\dagger_j b_{j+1} &=    \left(\cos \frac{\pi p}{n} - i \sin \frac{\pi p}{n} \right)   \beta^\dagger_p \beta_p + \left(\cos \frac{\pi p}{n} + i \sin \frac{\pi p}{n} \right)   \beta^\dagger_{-p} \beta_{-p}
\nonumber\\
b_j b_{j+1} &=   \left(\cos \frac{\pi p}{n} - i \sin \frac{\pi p}{n} \right)     \beta_{p} \beta_{-p} + \left(\cos \frac{\pi p}{n} + i \sin \frac{\pi p}{n} \right)     \beta_{-p} \beta_{p}
\end{align}

Comment: \begin{align}
\left(b^\dagger_j - b_j\right)\left(b^\dagger_{j+1} + b_{j+1}\right) &= b^\dagger_j b^\dagger_{j+1} - b_j b^\dagger_{j+1} + b^\dagger_j b_{j+1} - b_j b_{j+1}
\nonumber\\
 &=    \left(\cos \frac{\pi p}{n} + i \sin \frac{\pi p}{n} \right)     \beta^\dagger_{-p}  \beta^\dagger_p + \left(\cos \frac{\pi p}{n} - i \sin \frac{\pi p}{n} \right)     \beta^\dagger_{p}  \beta^\dagger_{-p}
\end{align}

Comment: \begin{align}
 &- \left(\cos \frac{\pi p}{n} + i \sin \frac{\pi p}{n} \right)     \beta_p  \beta^\dagger_p -  \left(\cos \frac{\pi p}{n} - i \sin \frac{\pi p}{n} \right)     \beta_{-p}  \beta^\dagger_{-p}

  & + \left(\cos \frac{\pi p}{n} - i \sin \frac{\pi p}{n} \right)   \beta^\dagger_p \beta_p + \left(\cos \frac{\pi p}{n} + i \sin \frac{\pi p}{n} \right)   \beta^\dagger_{-p} \beta_{-p}
  \nonumber\\
  &- \left(\cos \frac{\pi p}{n} - i \sin \frac{\pi p}{n} \right)     \beta_{p} \beta_{-p} - \left(\cos \frac{\pi p}{n} + i \sin \frac{\pi p}{n} \right)     \beta_{-p} \beta_{p}
\end{align}

Comment: To elaborate I show how I have determined $b^\dagger_j b^\dagger_{j+1}$.

Comment: \begin{align}
b^\dagger_j b^\dagger_{j+1} &= \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{p = \pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots, \pm \left(n-1\right)} e^{i\pi p j/n} \beta^\dagger_p\right) \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{p = \pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots, \pm \left(n-1\right)} e^{i\pi p \left(j+1\right)/n} \beta^\dagger_p\right)
\nonumber\\
&= \frac{1}{n} \left( \sum_{p = \pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots, \pm \left(n-1\right)} e^{i\pi p j/n} \beta^\dagger_p\right) \left( \sum_{p = \pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots, \pm \left(n-1\right)} e^{i\pi p \left(j+1\right)/n} \beta^\dagger_p\right)
\end{align}

Comment: \begin{align}
&= \frac{1}{n} \left( \sum_{p,q = \pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots, \pm \left(n-1\right)} e^{i\pi p j/n}   e^{i\pi q \left(j+1\right)/n} \beta^\dagger_p  \beta^\dagger_q\right) 
\nonumber\\
&= \frac{1}{n} \left( \sum_{p,q = \pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots, \pm \left(n-1\right)} e^{i\pi \left(p j + qj + q\right)/n}    \beta^\dagger_p  \beta^\dagger_q\right) 
\nonumber\\
&= \frac{1}{n} \left( \sum_{p,q = \pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots, \pm \left(n-1\right)} e^{i\pi q/n} e^{i\pi \left(p j + q j\right)/n}    \beta^\dagger_p  \beta^\dagger_q\right) 
\end{align}

Comment: \begin{align}
&= \frac{1}{n} \left( \sum_{p,q = \pm 1, \pm 3, \ldots, \pm \left(n-1\right)} e^{i\pi q/n} n \delta_{-p q}    \beta^\dagger_p  \beta^\dagger_q\right) 
\nonumber\\
&=   \sum_{p} e^{i\pi p/n}     \beta^\dagger_{-p}  \beta^\dagger_p
\nonumber\\
&=   \sum_{p} \left(\cos \frac{\pi p}{n} + i \sin \frac{\pi p}{n} \right)     \beta^\dagger_{-p}  \beta^\dagger_p
\end{align}

Comment: \begin{align}
&=    \left(\cos \frac{\pi p}{n} + i \sin \frac{\pi p}{n} \right)     \beta^\dagger_{-p}  \beta^\dagger_p + \left(\cos \frac{-\pi p}{n} + i \sin \frac{-\pi p}{n} \right)     \beta^\dagger_{p}  \beta^\dagger_{-p}
\nonumber\\
&=    \left(\cos \frac{\pi p}{n} + i \sin \frac{\pi p}{n} \right)     \beta^\dagger_{-p}  \beta^\dagger_p + \left(\cos \frac{\pi p}{n} - i \sin \frac{\pi p}{n} \right)     \beta^\dagger_{p}  \beta^\dagger_{-p}
\end{align}

Comment: @mas, could you please help me out here?

Comment: @Omar, let me check the calculation.

Comment: @mas, sorry for troubling you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{equation}
b_{j} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{p}e^{-i\pi pj/n}\beta_{p}\qquad b_{j+1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{p}e^{-i\pi q(j+1)/n}\beta_{q}
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
b_{j}^{\dagger}b_{j+1}^{\dagger} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{p,q}e^{\pi i(p+q)j/n}e^{\pi iq/n}\beta_{q}^{\dagger}\beta_{p}^{\dagger} = \sum_{p} e^{-\pi ip/n}\beta_{-p}^{\dagger}\beta_{p}^{\dagger}
\end{equation}
Likewise $b_{j}b_{j+1}= \sum_{p} e^{\pi ip/n}\beta_{-p}\beta_{p}$. Then
\begin{eqnarray}
b_{j}^{\dagger}b_{j+1}^{\dagger}-b_{j}b_{j+1} & = & \sum_{p} [e^{-\pi ip/n}\beta_{-p}^{\dagger}\beta_{p}^{\dagger}-e^{\pi ip/n}\beta_{-p}\beta_{p}] \\
& = & \sum_{p}e^{-\pi ip/n}[\beta_{-p}^{\dagger}\beta_{p}^{\dagger}-e^{2\pi ip/n}\beta_{-p}\beta_{p}]\\
& = & \sum_{p}e^{-\pi ip/n}[\beta_{-p}^{\dagger}\beta_{p}^{\dagger}-\beta_{-p}\beta_{p}]\quad\boxed{\text{using}~e^{2\theta}=1}\\
& = & \sum_{p}(\cos\frac{\pi p}{n}-i\sin\frac{\pi p}{n})[\beta_{-p}^{\dagger}\beta_{p}^{\dagger}-\beta_{-p}\beta_{p}]\\
& = & -2i\sum_{p}\sin\left(\frac{\pi p}{n}\right)[\beta_{-p}^{\dagger}\beta_{p}^{\dagger}-\beta_{-p}\beta_{p}] \\
\Rightarrow -\frac{1}{2}[b_{j}^{\dagger}b_{j+1}^{\dagger}-b_{j}b_{j+1}] & = & i\sum_{p}\sin\left(\frac{\pi p}{n}\right)[\beta_{-p}^{\dagger}\beta_{p}^{\dagger}-\beta_{-p}\beta_{p}] \\
\end{eqnarray}
Which is the desired expression. Lets check the term $\sum_{p}(\cos\frac{\pi p}{n}-i\sin\frac{\pi p}{n})[\beta_{-p}^{\dagger}\beta_{p}^{\dagger}-\beta_{-p}\beta_{p}]$ for $p=\pm 1$ (setting $\frac{1}{n}=m$)
\begin{eqnarray}
(\cos\pi m-i\sin\pi m)[\beta_{-1}^{\dagger}\beta_{1}^{\dagger}-\beta_{-1}\beta_{1}]+[\cos(-\pi m)-i\sin(-\pi m)][\beta_{1}^{\dagger}\beta_{-1}^{\dagger}-\beta_{1}\beta_{-1}] & = & -2i\sin(\pi m)[\beta_{-1}^{\dagger}\beta_{1}^{\dagger}-\beta_{-1}\beta_{1}]
\end{eqnarray}
(There $b_{-p}b_{p}=-b_{p}b_{-p}$ has been used). Therefore no contribution comes from cosine terms. Likewise rest of the expression follows.

Comment: @Omar, Do you find this calculation is correct?

Comment: why is $b_{-p}b_{p}=-b_{p}b_{-p}$?

Comment: Fermionic generators anti-commute. Check equation 4.15, of the paper.

Comment: I completely understand it. Sorry for missing the last thing out.

Comment: Go ahead. You from BD i guess.

Comment: yeah. What about you?

Comment: Same as you. But reside in BD.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41343/discussion-between-omar-shehab-and-mas).

Comment: If you have any problem, please post here. I will be happy to deal with that.

Comment: I have another question about the later part of the section. Thanks in advance. http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/263291/transforming-hamiltonian-expressed-in-the-fourier-transform-of-fermionic-operat